# why we use Thread for implementing `CurrentCulture` and `CurrentUICulture` in ASP.NET Multilingual website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, localization, internationalization, multilingual, globalization

In Internationalization, why do we use the **`Multithreading`** or **`Thread`**  for performing **`CurrentCulture`** and **`CurrentUICulture`** in Globalization and Localization in MVC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture
```

is for Dateformats, Numbers, etc. bit not the actual language. These format settings are already implemented in ASP.NET. So you just have to say you want to use en-US and you get the numbers in the USA format. If you switch to en-GB, you get them in the British format.

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture
```

is for the actual language that YOU have to implement with resource files (*.resx). This defines which resource file is used to load the language resources from.

You often support more CurrentCulture settings than CurrentUICulture.